# Testing events generated within React component using Jest or Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have created an react component to act as an autosaving input field. The intended behaviour is:

1. If the user hits Enter or clicks outside the box it will call its `onSubmit` prop with
   the value the user has entered.
2. If the user hits the Escape key it will reset the value to `props.lastSavedValue`.
3. When either Enter or Escape is pressed the input field is defocused.

The code of the component is:

```
class AutoSavingInput extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {currentValue: props.lastSavedValue || ''}
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <input
        ref={(input) => this.input = input}
        value={this.state.currentValue}
        onChange={(e) => this.setState({currentValue: e.target.value})}
        onBlur={() => this.props.onSubmit(this.state.currentValue)}
        onKeyUp={(event) => {
          switch (event.key) {
            case 'Enter':
              this.input.blur()
              break
            case 'Escape': {
              this.setState({currentValue: this.props.lastSavedValue},
                            () => this.input.blur())
              break
            }
          }
        }}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Testing the `blur` event with Jest or Enzyme is trivial but I am having trouble testing
the key press events. I have tried:

```
function setup () {
  const onSubmit = jest.fn()
  const component = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
    <AutoSavingInput lastSavedValue="last-saved-value" onSubmit={onSubmit} />
  )
  const node = ReactTestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(component, 'input')
  component.setState({currentValue: 'the-value'})
  return { component, node, onSubmit }
}

// THIS TEST SHOULD PASS BUT IT FAILS
it('submits when Enter key is pressed', () => {
  const { node, onSubmit } = setup()
  ReactTestUtils.Simulate.keyUp(node, {key: 'Enter'})
  expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('the-value')
})

// THIS TEST SHOULD FAIL BUT IT PASSES
it('does not submit when Escape key is pressed', () => {
  const { node, onSubmit } = setup()
  ReactTestUtils.Simulate.keyUp(node, {key: 'Escape'})
  expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0)
})
```

As the comments describe, the Enter key test fails when it should pass and the Escape key
test passes when it should fail. This is happening because in the test environment,
`this.input.blur()` is not triggering the `blur` event.

When I test in the browser, the code behaves as expected.

It is possible to write a Jest or Enzyme test which handles events emitted from within the component?

I've put the code in a create-react-app project here if anyone wants to experiment: https://github.com/RobbieClarken/testing-react-component-events

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `keyUp` event is meant to fire `this.input.blur()`, and you expect `blur()` to then trigger the component's `onBlur()` function and call `onSubmit()`. This may not be something you can easily test with Enzyme. There is not actually a DOM, so you may not be able to expect that `this.input.blur()` will actually trigger the input's `onBlur()` handler. You might have better luck testing what the `keyUp` event directly fires (`this.input.blur()` rather than `onSubmit()`).